# Код ES6 map() не работает в IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6

Обнаружил, что код ES6 `map()` и **``** не работают в **IE 11**
Как это участок кода переписать кроссбраузерно или какой использовать можно **polyfill** для этого?

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  const keys = ["hard", "soft"];

  document.head.appendChild((style => {
    style.textContent = keys.map(key => `
   #main-slider-wrapper .slider-key button[data-key="${key}"] {
    background-image:
     url(img/${key}-key-slider.png)
   }

   #main-slider-wrapper[data-key="${key}"] .slider img[src*="${key}-key"] {
    opacity: 1;
   }

   #main-slider-wrapper[data-key="${key}"] .slider-key button[data-key="${key}"] {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em #009af7) drop-shadow(0 0 0.2em rgba(255,255,255,0.5));
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em #009af7) drop-shadow(0 0 0.2em rgba(255,255,255,0.5));
   }
  `).join("\n\n");
    return style;
  })(document.createElement("style")));

  document.addEventListener("click", ({
    target
  }) => {
    if (!target.matches(
        `${keys.map(k => `[data-key="${k}"]`).join(", ")}, .slick-arrow`
      )) return;

    const root = target.closest("#main-slider-wrapper");
    const key = target.dataset.key;
    const index = keys.indexOf(key);
    root.dataset.key = key;

    for (const arrow of root.querySelectorAll(".slick-arrow")) {
      arrow.dataset.key = keys[
        (keys.length + (
          arrow.classList.contains("left") ? -1 : 1
        ) + index) % keys.length
      ];
    }
  });

  for (const e of document.querySelectorAll(`[data-key="${keys[0]}"]`))
    e.click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогу для того, чтобы решить задачу, вначале воспользовался [онлайн сервисом](https://babeljs.io/repl/), затем добавил [babel polyfill](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js), т.к. без него показывало ошибку:

> "Символ" не определен в IE после использования babel

И наконец, добавил еще 2 полифила: для [matches](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/polyfill-matches) и [closest](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/polyfill-closest) и вот тогда все заработало!

Answer (score 3):

В IE11 не работают [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), поэтому их использование нужно заменить обычным сложением, например:

```
`[data-key="${k}"]`
```

преобразуется в

```
'[data-key="'+k+'"]'
```

Comment: Воспользовался https://babeljs.io/repl/ Но, пока решило проблему лишь частично - остались вопросы к этому блоку, в частности к `matches` и `closest` - ie говорит, что не знает таких функций
`document.addEventListener("click", function (_ref) {
    var target = _ref.target;
    if (!target.matches("".concat(keys.map(function (k) {
      return "[data-key=\"".concat(k, "\"]");
    }).join(", "), ", .slick-arrow"))) return;
    var root = target.closest("#main-slider-wrapper");
    var key = target.dataset.key;
    var index = keys.indexOf(key);
    root.dataset.key = key;
}`

Comment: @Вася, и он их действительно может не знать. Можешь воспользоваться `jQuery`, там как раз одноименные функции есть. Либо добавить соответствующий [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill)

Comment: по идее должен знать, но показывает такие ошибки "Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "matchesSelector" и "Symbol" не определено"

Comment: @Вася, _Uses the non-standard name: msMatchesSelector_ например.